# Trouble writing fish if statement

Tags: shell, if-statement, syntax, zsh, fish

So I have the following if statement (originally from my .zshrc):

```
if [ -n "${NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS+x}" ]; then
  alias h='nvr -o'
  alias v='nvr -O'
  alias t='nvr --remote-tab'
fi
```

Now I am trying to port this across to my `config.fish`, I understand that it is to do with the `[` on the if but I can't quite figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[` is OK. The two parts that are different in fish are the +x expansion modifier, and the loop syntax.

In zsh, `"${NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS+x}"` evaluates to `x` if `$NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS` is set, and empty otherwise; then that is compared to see if it's empty. This seems to be a roundabout way to just check if the variable is set.

Regarding loops, fish blocks always end with `end`, and there is no need for `then` or `do`.

So this is the most direct port to fish:

```
if [ -n "$NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS" ]
    alias h='nvr -o'
    alias v='nvr -O'
    alias t='nvr --remote-tab'
end
```

And this is more idiomatic:

```
if set -q NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS
    abbr h 'nvr -o'
    abbr v 'nvr -O'
    abbr t 'nvr --remote-tab'
end
```

which uses the fish [abbreviation feature](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#abbr) that expands in place.

Comment: Thank you for such an extensive answer.